# Protecting Excel work book using SpreadsheetGear in C#

Tags: excel, spreadsheetgear

What is best possible way to protect Excel work book(read only) and work sheets without using

password using SpreadsheetGear dll in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting IWorksheet.ProtectContents to true protects a worksheet without attaching a password to it.

SpreadsheetGear 2009 does not support workbook protection / passwords. SpreadsheetGear 2010 does support workbook protection with a new IWorkbook.Protect(...) method, and also supports reading and writing password protected workbooks. We intend to release SpreadsheetGear 2010 this summer.

Comment: hey joe can you tell me that how to make excel cell contains read only in its xml file format.currently i am using Iworksheet.Protect(). which is making it read only in excel ,but i can change value in its xml file SharedString.xml . by opening excel file with Winzip and editing SharedString.xml on any editor.
 – Avinash